# How to solve issue with useEffect in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

How can I make `useEffect` have control over the component update?

I have this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api/data")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, []);
```

This brings me the information once but if I do something with an item within `data` the change is not shown in the component that shows that `data`.

If I use this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api/data")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, [data]);
```

It stays in an infinite update loop.

I only want it to change if any `data` change occurs, so that it doesn't remain in an infinite loop, how could I achieve this?

Exhibit:

In some `useEffect`s that I have used it asks me for dependencies but this particular one does not do so.

Comment: In your second `useEffect`, you are not using the `data` state value. You are calling `fetch` with a static URL and setting the `stores` as the response data. You need to provide more context. You typically will have your component take a prop that triggers a `useEffect` to fetch update data. You could also implement something like WebSockets to trigger a refetch.

Comment: I fixed a small error I had when writing, I'm not using "stores", my component state is "data", although the fact of using a static url makes me think: you say I need a refresh trigger or a dynamic url, Would you give me any suggestions? I understood your point

Comment: Why would you set the data every time the data changes? This is why you are looping indefinitely. If the data is already changes, why would you set it again? You need to add more context to your question. What is triggering the `useEffect`, because it is obviously not `data`.

Comment: because in that same component I use an "update" function to modify the "data" if required

Comment: I don't think you understand the flow of a React component.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setData instead of setStrores in the code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
 fetch("/api/data")
 .then((res) => res.json())
 .then((res) => {
  setData(res.data);
 })
 .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);
```

Comment: jajaja writing error, I have it like this "setData"

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you will get the `res.data` once since `useEffect` without dependency trigger once when component rendered.

In the second case, `setData` is called inside `useEffect` which mean the effect will run infinite time since `data` being set every render

Comment: I use setData when fetch returns the info to me then data I show it in a table with data.map

Comment: @miguelmorillo useEffect run if its dependency have changes, you setData when fetch return mean the data changes and it start fetch again cause infinity loop

Comment: I understand, now I know how to deal with the problem better, thanks for this